# Set queue name in yielded pipelines

Tags: python, google-app-engine, appengine-pipeline

I want to regulate the task queue name, on which the pipeline tasks run.
I see that this can be achieved via:

```
myPipeline = SumPipeline(future1, future2)
myPipeline.start(queue_name='myqueue')
```

But what happens if I don't start the pipeline manually but it is yielded by another pipeline? For instance:

```
class RootPipeline(pipeline.Pipeline):

    def run(self):
        yield SumPipeline(future1, future2)
```

Is it possible to have separate task queues for the yielding pipeline `RootPipeline` and the yielded pipeline `SumPipeline`? If yes, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not that familiar with the Python code but I wonder if overriding queue_name in SumPipeline to return the queue you want it to run on will not do the trick (as I could not see any other way).

```
class SumPipeline(pipeline.Pipeline):
  ....
  @property
  def queue_name(self):
    return "...."
```

Comment: Thanks ozarov. I'll give it a shot and update the question.

Comment: Gave it a shot but this doesn't work. All the tasks were added to the yielding pipeline's queue. Thanks.